# Custom container for iterating over combinations of elements from multiple sets

Tags: c++, combinatorics, iterator, collections

Motivated by some SO quesitons [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568287/implementing-an-iterator-over-combinations-of-many-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508192/c-how-to-traverse-through-different-set-elements-of-a-vector-in-specific-patte/50511337?noredirect=1#comment88036250_50511337)] I made an attempt at implementing a custom container with a bi-directional custom iterator for iterating over all combinations of elements from multiple sets.

I am quite unfamiliar with the topic, so any feedback on design (including naming) and performance is very appreciated.

Some implementation details:

- The container does not store all the combinations
- Combinations are calculated on the fly when iterator is incremented or decremented
- Combination is represented as a vector of iterators: one for each set
- When combinations iterator is dereferenced or arrow operator is called, combination is returned by value to avoid dangling

#### `combinations.hpp`

```
#ifndef COMBINATIONS_HPP
#define COMBINATIONS_HPP

#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// Precondition: all sets between iterators should be non-empty:
// contain at least 1 element
template <typename SetOfSetsIter>
class combinations
{
public:
    typedef combinations<SetOfSetsIter> Combination_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<SetOfSetsIter>::value_type Set;
    typedef typename std::vector<typename Set::const_iterator> Combination;

    typedef Combination value_type;
    typedef long long difference_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;

    class const_iterator
    {
    public:
        typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef typename Combination_type::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename Combination_type::value_type value_type;
        typedef const Combination reference;
        typedef const Combination pointer;

        const_iterator()
        {}
        const_iterator(const const_iterator& other)
            : first_(other.first_)
            , last_(other.last_)
            , combination_(other.combination_)
        {}
        const_iterator(SetOfSetsIter first, SetOfSetsIter last)
            : first_(first)
            , last_(last)
        {
            for(SetOfSetsIter it = first_; it != last_; ++it)
                combination_.push_back(it->begin());
        }
        static const_iterator make_end(SetOfSetsIter first, SetOfSetsIter last)
        {
            const_iterator res;
            res.first_ = first;
            res.last_ = last;
            SetOfSetsIter it = first;
            res.combination_.push_back(it->end());
            for(++it; it != last; ++it)
                res.combination_.push_back(--it->end());
            return res;
        }
        ~const_iterator()
        {}
        const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator other)
        {
            swap(*this, other);
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const const_iterator& other) const
        {
            return combination_ == other.combination_ &&
                   first_ == other.first_ && last_ == other.last_;
        }
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator& other) const
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        const_iterator& operator++()
        {
            typename Combination::iterator combIt = combination_.begin();
            for(SetOfSetsIter it = first_; it != last_; ++it, ++combIt)
            {
                if(++(*combIt) != it->end())
                    return *this;
                *combIt = it->begin();
            }
            set_to_end_();
            return *this;
        }
        const_iterator& operator--()
        {
            typename Combination::iterator combIt = combination_.begin();
            for(SetOfSetsIter it = first_; it != last_; ++it, ++combIt)
            {
                if(*combIt != it->begin())
                {
                    --(*combIt);
                    return *this;
                }
                *combIt = --it->end();
            }
            set_to_begin_();
            return *this;
        }
        Combination operator*() const
        {
            return combination_;
        }
        Combination operator->() const
        {
            return combination_;
        }
        friend void swap(
            const_iterator& first,
            const_iterator& second) // nothrow
        {
            std::swap(first.first_, second.first_);
            std::swap(first.last_, second.last_);
            std::swap(first.combination_, second.combination_);
        }
        void swap(Combination_type other)
        {
            swap(*this, other);
        }

    private:
        void set_to_end_()
        {
            typename Combination::iterator combIt = combination_.begin();
            SetOfSetsIter it = first_;
            *(combIt++) = (it++)->end();
            for(; it != last_; ++it, ++combIt)
                *combIt = --it->end();
        }
        void set_to_begin_()
        {
            typename Combination::iterator combIt = combination_.begin();
            for(SetOfSetsIter it = first_; it != last_; ++it, ++combIt)
                *combIt = it->begin();
        }
        friend class combinations<SetOfSetsIter>;

    private:
        SetOfSetsIter first_;
        SetOfSetsIter last_;
        Combination combination_;
    };

    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;

    combinations()
    {}
    combinations(SetOfSetsIter first, SetOfSetsIter last)
        : first_(first)
        , last_(last)
    {}
    combinations(const combinations<SetOfSetsIter>& other)
        : first_(other.first_)
        , last_(other.last_)
    {}
    ~combinations()
    {}
    combinations& operator=(const combinations<SetOfSetsIter>& other)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const combinations<SetOfSetsIter>& other) const
    {
        return first_ == other.first_ && last_ == other.last_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const combinations<SetOfSetsIter>& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return const_iterator(first_, last_);
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const
    {
        return begin();
    }
    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return const_iterator::make_end(first_, last_);
    }
    const_iterator cend() const
    {
        return end();
    }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const
    {
        return crbegin();
    }
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const
    {
        return const_reverse_iterator(end());
    }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const
    {
        return crend();
    }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const
    {
        return const_reverse_iterator(begin());
    }
    friend void swap(
        combinations<SetOfSetsIter>& first,
        combinations<SetOfSetsIter>& second) // nothrow
    {
        std::swap(first.first_, second.first_);
        std::swap(first.last_, second.last_);
    }
    void swap(combinations<SetOfSetsIter> other)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
    }
    size_type size() const
    {
        size_type result = 1;
        for(SetOfSetsIter it = first_; it != last_; ++it)
            result *= it->size();
        return result;
    }
    size_type max_size() const
    {
        return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
    }
    bool empty() const
    {
        return first_ == last_;
    }

private:
    SetOfSetsIter first_;
    SetOfSetsIter last_;
};

template <typename SetOfSets>
combinations<typename SetOfSets::const_iterator>
make_combinations(const SetOfSets& data)
{
    return combinations<typename SetOfSets::const_iterator>(
        data.cbegin(), data.cend());
}

#endif // COMBINATIONS_HPP
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include "combinations.hpp"

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<int> Set;
    typedef std::vector<Set> SetOfSets;
    typedef SetOfSets::const_iterator SetOfSetsCIt;
    const SetOfSets data = {{2, 4}, {1, 3, 8}, {7, 5}};
    {
        std::cout << "First to last-------" << std::endl;
        typedef combinations<SetOfSetsCIt> Combinations;
        Combinations cmbs = make_combinations(data);
        {
            std::cout << "Forward:" << std::endl;
            for(const auto& combination : cmbs)
            {
                for(const auto& elemIt : combination)
                    std::cout << *elemIt << " ";
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
        {
            std::cout << "Reverse:" << std::endl;
            for(Combinations::const_reverse_iterator combIt = cmbs.crbegin();
                combIt != cmbs.crend();
                ++combIt)
            {
                for(const auto& elemIt : *combIt)
                    std::cout << *elemIt << " ";
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    {
        std::cout << "Last to first-------" << std::endl;
        typedef SetOfSets::const_reverse_iterator SetOfSetsCRIt;
        typedef combinations<SetOfSetsCRIt> Combinations;
        Combinations cmbs(data.crbegin(), data.crend());
        {
            std::cout << "Forward:" << std::endl;
            for(Combinations::const_iterator cmbIt = cmbs.begin();
                cmbIt != cmbs.end();
                ++cmbIt)
            {
                Combinations::Combination c = *cmbIt;
                std::reverse(c.begin(), c.end());
                for(const auto& it : c)
                    std::cout << *it << " ";
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
        {
            std::cout << "Reverse:" << std::endl;
            for(Combinations::const_reverse_iterator cmbIt = cmbs.crbegin();
                cmbIt != cmbs.crend();
                ++cmbIt)
            {
                Combinations::Combination c = *cmbIt;
                std::reverse(c.begin(), c.end());
                for(const auto& it : c)
                    std::cout << *it << " ";
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output of `main.cpp`:

```
First to last-------
Forward:
2 1 7 
4 1 7 
2 3 7 
4 3 7 
2 8 7 
4 8 7 
2 1 5 
4 1 5 
2 3 5 
4 3 5 
2 8 5 
4 8 5 
Reverse:
4 8 5 
2 8 5 
4 3 5 
2 3 5 
4 1 5 
2 1 5 
4 8 7 
2 8 7 
4 3 7 
2 3 7 
4 1 7 
2 1 7 
Last to first-------
Forward:
2 1 7 
2 1 5 
2 3 7 
2 3 5 
2 8 7 
2 8 5 
4 1 7 
4 1 5 
4 3 7 
4 3 5 
4 8 7 
4 8 5 
Reverse:
4 8 5 
4 8 7 
4 3 5 
4 3 7 
4 1 5 
4 1 7 
2 8 5 
2 8 7 
2 3 5 
2 3 7 
2 1 5 
2 1 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to write an iterator, start out with Boost.Iterator.  It has a `iterator_facade` and `iterator_adaptor` class that makes short (and *accurate*) work of it.

If you never store the combinations at all, but compute them on the fly, what you really have is a [Range Adaptor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html).  If you have a function that maps input (index?) to outputs, it is quick work to use an existing library to do that.  Calculating changes with ++ and −− rather than computing it from scratch is more difficult, and I think can be done with `iterator_facade` where you just supply increment and decrement functions.